# Увеличение текста в зависимости от размера экрана

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть Prefeb UI текста который я создаю , но проблема в том что он не подстраивается  под размер экрана :

Иерархия:

Manager - пустой объект ;
PopUpCanvas - canvas;
Imaga - картинка (для создания текста на её месте);

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Canvas :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Prefab :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скрипт:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;
using TMPro;
public class PopupScript : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject popUP; // prefab to instantiate
    public Canvas canvas; // father canvas
    public Transform ObjectforSpawn;
   // private Vector2 position = new Vector2(0, 0);
    void Start()
    {
       // position.x = 96.7f;
      //  position.y = 331.6f;
    }

    public void PopUP(int Score)
    {

        GameObject inst = (GameObject)Instantiate(popUP, ObjectforSpawn.position, Quaternion.identity);
        inst.transform.SetParent(canvas.transform);
        var textMeshes = GetComponentsInChildren<Text>();

        foreach (var tm in textMeshes)
        {
            tm.text = Score.ToString();
        }
        Destroy(inst, 4.0f);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

За то, каким образом будут изменять свои размеры элементы UI отвечает компонент [CanvasScaler](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-CanvasScaler.html), который должен быть добавлен на самый верхний в иерархии объект, на котором есть компонент Canvas. Подробнее о настройках можете прочитать в документации по компоненту.

За то, каким образом каждый объект UI-я изменяет свою позицию или размер при изменении разрешения отвечают настройки RectTransform-а компонентов и их Anchor. Подробнее об адаптивном интерфейсе можно прочитать у Unity в спец.статье: ["Создание интерфейса (UI) под разные разрешения экрана"](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/HOWTO-UIMultiResolution.html)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ ,но я так и не смог понять почему в одном canvas'e текст увеличивается , а в другом идентичном canvas'e нет . Единственная разницы только в том как создается текст (В первом я создаю его сразу как простой объект , а другой  через некоторое время как префаб  .)

Comment: @Veudd, все дело в конце создания объекта - когда вы создаёте объект, он создаётся вне канваса и имеет определённый размер. Далее вы назначаете этому объекту родителя через SetTransform(Transform parent) - по умолчанию у этого метода стоит "сохранять размер" - это значит, что если у нового родителя скейл 0.5, то у чайлда станет 2, чтобы сохранить размер. Чтобы размер подстраивался используйте вот так `inst.transform.SetParent(canvas.transform, false)`;